# Disabling a fieldset with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function disableField() {
  "use strict";
  var a = document.forms["myForm"]["donate_type"].value;

  if (a == "pet") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  }
  if (a == "money") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  }
  if (a == "service") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

I try to call this function by having it on the different options. 
I had also tried putting the entire select statement in a div and have the function call on click after the div tag

```
<form name="myForm">
<select name="donate_type" onchange="disableField()">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="pet">Pet</option>
<option value="money">Monetary</option>
<option value="service">Service</option>
</select>

<fieldset id ="pet">
<legend>Pet</legend>
<form>
Please select the pet you would like to Donate<br>
<select name="pet" >
<option value="dog">Dog</option>
<option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
</select>

<fieldset id="monetary" >
<legend>Monetary</legend>
<form>
Requested Amount<input type="number" name="donate_amount">
Method of payment
<select name="donate_type" onclick = "">
<option value="credit_card">Credit Card</option>
<option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
</select>
</form>
```

But I can't seem to get the selected fieldsets to be disabled.
I have 3 different fieldsets with the different titles pet, money and service
Could someone tell me what error I've made?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `disable` should be `disabled`

Comment: Noted, changed but still isn't doing what it should.

Comment: Could you add you html elements that have Ids of pet,money.service

Comment: <fieldset id="pet" >
<fieldset id="monetary" >
<fieldset id="service" >
I tried earlier but it told me too much code .
@singsuyash

Comment: I'm having difficulties reproducing any problems because there isn't enough code here. Can you please [edit] the question to contain a [mcve]?

Comment: @4castle Edited, sorry, didnt know about the verifiable example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing a bit of code which made testing your code challenging. I added the missing elements based on your description and the references.

I replaced the `onclick` listener placed on the options with an `onchange` listener on the select.
I also fixed your `disable`/`disabled` typos.

```js
function disableField() {
  var a = document.forms["myForm"]["donate_type"].value;

  if (a === "pet") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  } else if (a === "money") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  } else if (a === "service") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  }
}
document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <select name="donate_type" onchange="disableField()">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="pet">Pet</option>
  <option value="money">Monetary</option>
  <option value="service">Service</option>
</select>
</form>

<fieldset id="pet">
  <input type="text" placeholder="pet">
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="money">
  <input type="text" placeholder="money">
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="service">
  <input type="text" placeholder="service">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks for the snip. I tried i tried it, but after selecting an option, your still able to type into the other fields,

Comment: @JhevanteMcdonald Did you run the example in my answer via *Run code snippet* and it failed?

Comment: Yeah, after selecting Pet.Monetary/Service, i can type in all 3 fields.

Comment: @JhevanteMcdonald It should work as you've specified with your logic. That only *Pet* is writable when that option is selected and *Service* when that is selected and so on. You did not specify anything else.

Comment: my apologies for not being clear, but when x option is selected, I'm trying to make it so that the users can't enter anything in a fieldset with a different id.

Comment: @JhevanteMcdonald Which is the case, until the user changes the selection. You could clear all the relevant form elements inside the if-statements if this is of concern.

Comment: I tried typing j after selecting the different options
for the 3 boxes, I ended up with 4 j's if you understand how I tried to check. It allows me to enter information in anything no matter what option I select, both in snip and my code .

Comment: This is the functionality I'm looking for, much appreciated it. but it doesn't work with the code I have, so I will review, but with this as a guide I'm sure to get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function on `select` element. Try the following:

```js
function disableField() {
  var a = document.forms["myForm"]["donate_type"].value;
  if (a === "pet") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  }
  if (a === "money") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = true;
  }
  if (a === "service") {
    document.getElementById("pet").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("money").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("service").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="pet" name="" value="pet"/>
    <input type="text" id="money" name="" value="money"/>
    <input type="text" id="service" name="" value="service"/>
    <select name="donate_type" onchange="disableField()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="pet">Pet</option>
        <option value="money">Monetary</option>
        <option value="service">Service</option>
    </select>
</form>
```